# Ajuda com Controle de Versão - GIT/ SVN

Tags: linux, git, svn, versionamento, tortoisesvn

entrei em uma empresa que trabalha com GIT, eu trabalhava com SVN, e estou tendo algumas dificuldades para me adaptar ao GIT. Então gostaria de migrar para o SVN, já que a a equipe são apenas de dois programadores.

Temos o repositório GIT em um servidor linux.
Para linux, encontrei o Rabbitvcs, que inclusive tem suporte ao git.

Como faço essa migração, ou acham melhor eu permanecer com o GIT utilizando o Rabbitvcs? Podem me ajudar com essa e as dúvidas seguintes de configuração?

Comment: Para manter organizado você deve fazer apenas uma pergunta. A pergunta será fechada porque precisamos de perguntas respostas objetivas, respostas que dizem "eu uso isto e aconselho você usar também" não ajudam ninguém aprender nada. Se deixar a parte da migração invalidará as respostas dadas até agora que optaram por opinar. Então acho que a pergunta não tem salvação. Crie uma nova sobre a migração que pode ser interessante. Estou votando para fechar por causa da parte que pede opinião que é a parte que consideraram relevante e responderam. Essas respostas são só "minha preferência é essa".

Comment: Muda a pergunta para como utilizar o git

Comment: Ele não pode adaptar a pergunta para atender uma resposta que não responde ao que foi perguntado. A pergunta está inviabilizada porque as duas respostas respondem coisas diferentes. A intenção dele não é perguntar como o Git funciona. Ele até pode fazer isto em outra pergunta se achar que deve mas depois que respostas foram dadas fica complicado mudar o foco da pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, aconselho fortemente a utilização do Git, pois é a ferramenta de controle de versão mais utilizada atualmente, e nunca é bom ficar desatualizado. O Git não é o mais utilizado por acaso. Segue as vantagens sobre os demais:

- Velocidade
- Design simples
- Suporte forte para desenvolvimento não linear
- Totalmente distribuído
- Habilidade para lidar com grande volume de maneira eficiente

Esse guia [aqui](http://git.huit.harvard.edu/guide/index.pt_BR.html) é ótimo e explica os comandos do git em um fluxo de execução. Se você souber um pouco de inglês o github também tem [este ótimo tutorial online](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)

Basicamente você irá utilizar os comandos `add`, `commit`, `push` para adicionar informações. E os comandos `fetch` e `pull` para atualizar seu projeto.

Recomendo também a utilização de branchs. Uma ferramenta muito boa para esse controle de branch é o [Gitflow](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.pt_BR.html)

Answer (score 0):

Aqui na empresa utilizamos o Subversion, já a um bom tempo.

http://svn-ref.assembla.com/subversion-server-guide-linux.html

Quanto a questões de migração não sei o que te dizer.